# Fade transition - fade vs. fadefast vs. fadeslow

Tags: ffmpeg, transitions

In the `xfade` filter, the speed of transition may be controlled by the `duration=` parameter – longer duration implies slower transition and vice versa.

So why are there – beside the `fade` value for the `transition=` parameter – other 2 values for the same effect, `fadefast` and `fadeslow`? What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They differ in rate of progression, i.e. fade is a linear progression, so that at half the duration, fade status is 50% i.e. both inputs are equally mixed. For fadefast, it starts fast and then slows down. Opposite for fadeslow.